# Close terminal window once application is opened

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, terminal, xfce4-terminal

Is it possible to close the parent terminal window once an application has been loaded?

I have a program I need to run using `root` privileges to work properly and currently I have made a script file which checks if the user is `root` if not then they are asked to confirm the `root` password before the application is loaded.

#### Original

Here is the contents of my script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then 
    echo "You need root privileges to run this utility"
    echo "Do you want to continue? (y/n):"
    read userInput
    
    if [ $userInput == "y" ] || [ $userInput == "Y" ]
      then 
        sudo ./myGuiProgram
      exit
    elif [ $userInput == "n" ] || [ $userInput == "N" ]
      then
        echo "Exiting now..." 
      exit 
    fi
  exit
elif [ "$EUID" -eq 0 ]
  then
    ./myGuiProgram 
  exit
fi
```

Is there anything I can add to this that will close the terminal window and not `myGuiProgram` ?

On my Centos 7 machine I have a desktop config file which executes the script file which in turns runs `myGuiProgram`

#### 2nd Attempt

I've modified my script since, but still no luck. This method allows me to exit the terminal window manually without closing my program

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then 
    echo "You need root privileges to run this utility"
    echo "Do you want to continue? (y/n):"
    read userInput
    
    if [ $userInput == "y" ] || [ $userInput == "Y" ]
      then 
        sudo nohup ./myGuiProgram > /dev/null & disown && kill $PPID
    elif [ $userInput == "n" ] || [ $userInput == "N" ]
      then
        echo "Exiting now..."  
    fi
elif [ "$EUID" -eq 0 ]
  then
    nohup ./myGuiProgram > /dev/null & disown && kill $PPID
fi
```

#### MARco Working Solution

New changes made based on @MARco response. This method works well.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then 
    echo "You need root privileges to run this utility"
    echo "Do you want to continue? (y/n):"
    read userInput
    
    if [ $userInput == "y" ] || [ $userInput == "Y" ]
      then 
        sudo -b nohup ./myGuiProgram 2>&1> /dev/null
    elif [ $userInput == "n" ] || [ $userInput == "N" ]
      then
        echo "Exiting now..."
        sleep 1
        exit 0
    fi
elif [ "$EUID" -eq 0 ]
  then
    nohup ./myGuiProgram > /dev/null 2>&1> /dev/null & 
fi
kill $(ps -ho ppid -p $(ps -ho ppid -p $$))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I launch a GUI program from a terminal but close the terminal once it's launched?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587109/how-can-i-launch-a-gui-program-from-a-terminal-but-close-the-terminal-once-its)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for `myGuiProgram` to error out if it's not being started by `root`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run a command which will survive terminal close?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-run-a-command-which-will-survive-terminal-close)

Comment: @Quasímodo thanks for the suggestion. I'm attempting to do what shown in the feed but I keep getting a `command not found` error in my terminal window

Comment: @Panki true I could cause an error if it's not been started in `root`, but I want to at least inform the user and give them the ability to try confirming `root` privileges for me. Think of it like Windows UAC control maybe. My script file will be loaded from a desktop config file which then loads the program

Comment: @thanasisp Thanks for the link I have tried this method as well with no luck. I'm doing something wrong somewhere. I've added a new line to my script which does what I need almost. The issue being it closes the program at the same time: `nohup ./myGuiProgram > /dev/null & disown && kill -9 $PPID`

Comment: I believe it would be ideal to just `exit` the shell after nohuping or disowning or similar.

Comment: @thanasisp I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying I just need to add another `exit` statement somewhere in my script?

Comment: No, one is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can launch a gui *program* and close immediately the xterm that launched it with:

`exec` *program*`&exit`

or better

`exec` *program*`2>&1>/dev/null &exit`

You have a script that acquire input still in terminal, so the terminal for you doesn't have to exit soon, so here is the solution:

1. replace `./myGuiProgram` with `nohup ./myGuiProgram 2>&1>/dev/null &`
2. replace `sudo ./myGuiProgram` with `nohup sudo ./myGuiProgram 2>&1>/dev/null &`
3. remove all the four `exit` in your script (the way you used it is only redundant)
4. append `sleep 1` in the end of your script

launch the script in the terminal with

```
exec script
```

Note: the only way to launch the script without `exec` and have the external exec functionality within the script is not very nice: end suddenly xterm (parent of xterm's shell process accepting `script` command which is parent pf bash the script interpreter) within the script with

```
kill $(ps -ho ppid -p $(ps -ho ppid -p $$))
```

as last line of the script

The need to use 1. and 2. also gave me an idea: nohup should have an argument to ignore program's output because otherwise it only add a extensive pipe to what is wasted

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried your method but the `sleep 1` is too short of a window to enter the `root` user password. I've updated my question incorporating your method and I can confirm that it worked great. It would be nice to not need the `sleep` command.

Comment: I didn't know your sudo configuration, I assumed NOPASS, the `sleep 1` was not in the purpose to give time to enter a password... the sudo ... & is not for you then, you have to invert `sudo -b nohup ./myGuiProgram 2>&1>/dev/null`

Comment: Thank you very much @MARco this line works wonders and looks do to what I need.